# Calling function in Child component controller from Parent Controller using aura:method not working

Tags: lightning-aura-components, javascript, lightning

I have a parent component controller from which I am calling a Child controller  function using `aura:metho`d as described in https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/developer-relations/2017/04/lightning-inter-component-communication-patterns.html

But now working. Giving the error:

> c:WspPOLITICS$controller$save [childComponent.callScoremethod is not
>   a function]

## Parent Component

```
   <aura:component access="global">
   <!--some code-->
      <c:questionSectionPolitic aura:id="childQuestion" />
     <button type="button" aura:id="saveAndReturn" class="slds-button slds-button--neutral slds-button slds-button--brand slds-hide" onclick="{!c.save}" >Save and return
     </button>
 </aura:component>
```

## ParentComponent Controller

```
save : function(component,helper,event){
  var childComponent = component.find("childQuestion");
  console.log('childComponent-->'+childComponent);
  childComponent.callScoremethod(); }
```

## Child Component

```
   <aura:component access="global">
   <aura:method name="callScoremethod" action="{!c.calcScore}" access="PUBLIC"></aura:method>
   <!--some code-->
   </aura:component>
```

## Child Controller

```
calcScore : function(component,event,handler){
 <!Some logic-->
 }
```

Comment: I have already gone through the same and as they suggested I have used the aura:method

Comment: Does your components are in the same namespace? You should try to put a global access on the `aura:method` like this: `access="global"`

Comment: It was already in public access but I tried it with global access but same error

Comment: well, hehe, i copy posted your code and it seems to work =P